# How to create while loop on selenium

Tags: python, selenium, while-loop

```
while True:
 ID = driver.find_element_by_id("id")
 ID.send_keys("user123")
 ID.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

portal = driver.find_element_by_id("portal")
portal.click()
```

I am trying to ask the bot to keep keying the id until the element "portal" is clickable. How to make them in a while loop? Or any other ways to make it?

Comment: `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "portal")))`

Comment: Both answers are wrong. You do not need a loop.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is an "Expected Condition" which makes this pretty easy.  See the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

portal = driver.find_element_by_id("portal")

while not (EC.element_to_be_clickable(portal)):
 ID = driver.find_element_by_id("id")
 ID.send_keys("user123")
 ID.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

portal.click();
```

Comment: Question was till portal you need to send keys to ID . So while loop is needed here with condition portal is clickable.

Comment: WIth this answer you are just waiting with condition till portal is enabled and visible, but not telling till when you have to send keys to ID

Comment: @Sonali Thank you for pointing that out, I misunderstood the question. I edited my answer so that it actually solves the right problem.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something I don't think I'm telling it to wait in the loop?

Answer (score -2):

As you want to feed the iD keys till Portal is clickable, your code should be like this

```
portal = driver.find_element_by_id("portal")
    
while portal.is_enabled:
 ID = driver.find_element_by_id("id")
 ID.send_keys("user123")
 ID.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
 portal.click
```

Comment: @C.Peck: if you check Portal.is_enabled , it check if its enabled or not. There is never only oneway to achieve this. EC.element_to_be _clicdkable is another way. You don't have to be mean to prove your answer is correct.

Comment: 1. OP wanted to wait for the element to be *clickable*, not just enabled. 2. There is never only one way to achieve something. But there is a most readable, reasonable solution.